# "Specified title already exists" error when trying to create a new page

Tags: wiki

I am trying to create a new page by going to "Site Actions/new page" first it gives me a little modal page which contains two buttons <kbd>Create</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and following message:

> In order to create wiki pages on this site, there must be a default
>   wiki page library and a site assets library. Would you like to create
>   those document libraries now?

When I click on Create button it generates a new modal which says:

> Error A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the
>   specified title already exists in this Web site.  Please choose
>   another title.

I haven't chosen or entered any title. Appreciate any kind of advice.

Comment: What site template did you use? Are there currently any lists called 'Site Pages' or 'Site Assets'?

Comment: "New page" link in Site action menu generates same error (above) regardless where I am and regardless which webtemplate I have used. most of my webtemplate are based on STS. BaseTemplateName="STS"  BaseTemplateID="1"

Answer (score 1):

I would view all site content and see if you have an existing Site Pages and Site Assets libraries. It sounds like either, the site had publishing turned on at some point and then that was turned off or the publishing features were not fully provisioned when they were turned on. If you have the "Site Pages" and "Site Assets" try either renaming them or deleting them (if you have nothing in them) and then creating your new page.